# instruction to copy lower 32 bits of a register to upper 32 bits

Tags: assembly, x86-64

Is there a x86 instruction to directly replicate the lower 32 bits of a x86_64 register to upper 32 bits?

```
Example : rbx -> 0x0123456789ABCDEF
Resultant rbx -> 0x89ABCDEF89ABCDEF
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm remembering my assembly class correctly, only the lowest two bytes in each register are individually addressable (al, ah, bl, bh, etc.).  So if you're looking for a single instruction, you're probably out of luck.

If it can be multiple instructions, I'd probably go with a combination of left shift and masking (pardon my pseudocode - it's been a while):

```
tmp = rbx
#Make sure you're using the version of left shift that zeroes the right bits:
tmp = tmp << 32
rbx = rbx & 0x00000000ffffffff
rbx = rbx | tmp
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: The "rbx = rbx & 0x00000000ffffffff" could be simplified to "ebx = ebx" (when writing 32-bit registers this architecture always clears the upper 32 bits of its 64-bit counterpart)

Answer (score 0):

There's a tradeoff between front-end throughput (total uops) vs. latency if you have AVX-512 or BMI2.

The standard way uses pure integer regs. A left shift will leave the low 32 bits zero, and writing a 32-bit register [will zero-extend to 64 bits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11177137/why-do-x86-64-instructions-on-32-bit-registers-zero-the-upper-part-of-the-full-6).  You can use any other register as the temporary, no advantage to RAX.

```
  mov  eax, ebx           ; EBX = RBX & 0xFFFFFFFF
  shl  rbx, 32
  or   rbx, rax
```

Compared to the other answer, MOV is creating a "tmp" copy *as well* as doing the truncation.  It would be worse if we copied and shifted in RAX, and separately had to truncate RBX in-place.

Throughput cost: 3 uops for the front-end, 2 for the back-end (assuming `mov` is eliminated).
Latency cost: 2 cycles: SHL-immediate and OR are single-cycle on all CPUs since P4.  MOV either has zero latency (eliminated) or can run in parallel with SHL.

---

**With [BMI2 `rorx`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/rorx) to copy-and-swap-halves of a 64-bit register, we can get it done in 2 instructions, into a different register only.**  But one of those instructions is `shrd` which is single-uop 3c latency on Intel Sandybridge-family (with an immediate count) but slower and 6 uops on AMD Zen.  RORX is efficient everywhere, single uop 1c latency.

```
; Intel SnB 4c latency, 2 uops.  AMD Zen: 3c latency, 7 uops
    rorx   rax, rbx, 32          ; top half of RAX = EBX 
    shrd   rax, rbx, 32          ; shift in another copy of EBX
                         ; RAX = EBX:EBX, RBX = untouched
```

So on Intel SnB-family, e.g. Skylake, total of 4 cycle latency, 2 uops (front-end and back-end, running on different ports).

On AMD Zen and Zen2, interestingly the latency ([uops.info](https://www.uops.info/html-lat/ZEN2/SHRD_IMMB_R64_R64_I8-Measurements.html)) from operand 1 -> 1 (in this case from RAX input to output) is only 2 cycles.  (And only 1 cycle from operand 2 -> 1, but RAX comes from RORX so it's ready after RBX, no way to take advantage of that that I can see.)  So total latency only 3 cycles.  But the throughput cost is fairly high, 6 uops.

---

The other 2-uop way requires AVX-512 so no current AMD CPUs can run it at all, rather than just slower like the BMI2 version.  The total latency is 6 cycles on Skylake-X (See ["experiment 49" on uops.info's test results](https://www.uops.info/html-lat/SKX/VPBROADCASTD_EVEX_XMM_R32-Measurements.html) for SKX `vpbroadcastd` latency, where they used this in an unrolled loop to create a loop-carried dependency chain specifically to measure the RBX->RBX latency).

```
  vpbroadcastd xmm0, ebx       ; AVX-512VL.  Single-uop on current Intel
  vmovq        rbx, xmm0       ; AVX1
```

This appears to have zero advantage over the rorx/shrd version: slower on Intel's current AVX-512 CPUs.

Except on Knight's Landing (where `shrd r64,r64,imm` is *very* slow; 1 uops, 11c throughput and latency, although `rorx` is 1c).  [Agner Fog](https://agner.org/optimize/) doesn't have timings for KNL's `vpbroadcastd/q xmm, r`, but even if it's 2 uops this is probably faster.

---

Without AVX-512, there's no advantage to using XMM registers if the data originally started in a GP integer register (instead of memory) and you need it back there, although it is possible:

```
; generally slower than the integer shl/or version
movd       xmm0, ebx
punpckldq  xmm0, xmm0     ; duplicate the low 32 bits
movq       rbx, xmm0
```

On Skylake, a `movd xmm, reg`/`movd reg,xmm` round-trip has 4 cycle latency (per https://uops.info/ testing), so this will have a total of 5.  It costs 3 uops, but on Intel Haswell / Skylake and similar CPUs 2 of them need port 5: `movq xmm, r64` and the shuffle.  Depending on the surrounding code, this could be a throughput bottleneck.

Latency is also worse on some earlier CPUs, notably Bulldozer-family which is fortunately now obsolete.  But even [on Zen2](https://www.uops.info/html-lat/ZEN2/VMOVQ_R64_XMM-Measurements.html), the movd/movq round trip has 6 cycle latency, plus another 1 cycle for the shuffle.

If your data started in memory, you could load it with
`vbroadcastss xmm0, [mem]` (AVX1) / `vmovq rbx, xmm0`.  Broadcast-loads are handled purely by the load port in modern Intel and AMD CPUs, for element sizes of 4 bytes or wider.

**If you want to store many copies to memory (like for `wmemset`)**, you'll want to use 16-byte stores at least, so you'd `pshufd xmm0, xmm0, 0` (SSE2) or `vpbroadcastd ymm0, xmm0` (AVX2) to broadcast into a whole vector.  If you just need 8 bytes of it as part of the cleanup for that, you can of course use `movq [mem], xmm0`

---

BMI2 [`shlx`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/sarx:shlx:shrx) is only available in `shlx reg, reg, reg` form, not with an immediate count.  With a `32` in a register, you could use this in a loop to produce the result **without destroying the input.**

```
  mov edx, 32     ; outside a loop

;inside a loop:
...
  shlx rax, rbx, rdx
  mov  ecx, ebx
  or   rax, rcx
...                     ; RAX = EBX:EBX.   RBX unmodified.
```

This has the same 2c latency as the normal SHL version, for the same reasons.

Comment: You can do it in 2 instructions w/ vanilla x86 with something like `mov ebx, ebx; imul rbx, 0x10000001`. Of course, 0x10000001 doesn't fit in an imm32, so you'd have to load it as a [memory source operand](https://godbolt.org/z/bKaob3) to stay at two instructions. Not really useful, just a thought experiment :).